# Virtualbox SOCKS proxy

Tags: virtualbox, socks-proxy

I'm using ssh to establish a SOCKS proxy within a Virtualbox guest machine (Debian). I've confirmed that it works within the guest system, but when I try to use it in my host system (Windows) via Firefox, it gives an error:

> Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing
>   connections.

I tried NAT and port-forwarded the appropriate port. Then I tried using a bridged adapter and used the guest machine's IP rather than 127.0.0.1. Neither method worked.

Comment: if using a bridged connection or forwarding through the vbox NAT isn't working, the issue sounds like port inaccessibility on debian itself. if you telnet to the proxy address and port, do you get a rejection message immediately, or does it just never connect? also look for your proxy port in `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep portnum`. is it attached to 127.0.x.y, your host IP, or 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @Frank Thomas: I've tried running a web server in the guest system, and I've been able to connect to that through the host system. Edit: It's attached to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: if the process is attached to 127.0.0.1, then only the local host can connect to it. look up how to enable remote connections to the service you are running. its usually in the main config file, and refers to interface or IP bindings.

Comment: @Frank Thomas: I don't have telnet on my host system. Is there another way or do I have to install it? By the way the web server is nginx in case that makes a difference.

Comment: check my latest edit. that its bound to 127.0.0.1 is your issue.

Comment: @Frank Thomas: That did the trick. When calling the ssh command, I specified 0.0.0.0 as the bind address. I'll check if NAT works as well. In the meantime, write it up as an answer :). Thanks a lot. Edit: Works with NAT as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the service is not accessible when the virtual nic is in either bridged mode, or is in NAT mode with a correctly configured forward rule, the issue is likely to be with the guest server, or the service itself.

Many services are not configured to accept remote connections by default, and open network ports for listening on the loop back network interface only. To determine what interface your service is bound to, use this command:

Linux:

```
# netstat -ntlup | grep portnumber
```

windows:

```
netstat -abno | FINDSTR LISTENING
```

and make note of the IP address the port/process is bound to.

```
 # netstat -ntlup | grep 53
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      835/dnsmasq     
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53           0.0.0.0:*                           835/dnsmasq
```

shows the dnsmasq service running on the loopback interface (127.0.x.y), and can only be accessed by processes running on the localhost.

```
# netstat -ntlup | grep 445
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      566/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      566/smbd
```

However shows the service listening on ALL interfaces (0.0.0.0).

finally,

```
# netstat -ntlup | grep 138
    udp        0      0 10.0.2.255:138          0.0.0.0:*                           960/nmbd        
    udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:138           0.0.0.0:*                           960/nmbd
```

shows the service listening on eth0 (host IP), and any broadcasts received on eth0 (host network broadcast address ending in .255) since Samba protocols use IP broadcasts.

Each service has its own means of enabling remote connections. this is somthing that must be configured in the service itself (no OS level control), because when the service opens the port for listening, it specifies the details of what interface to bind to. Usually (in linux) it involves specifying the interface binding in the services main configuration file, and restarting the service. In Windows, you are more likely to find a checkbox saying "allow remote connections" or some such, but you usually still have to restart the service for the change to take effect.

Comment: I'll just add that with OpenSSH in particular, you can either specify the bind address as an argument when starting the SOCKS server (`-D addr:port`) or you can enable the `GatewayPorts` setting in your configuration file so that it binds to the wildcard address by default.